# (Relaychain) received an unexpected `CollationSeconded`: unknown statement

Tags: untagged

Anyone knows if the following log may be indicative of some bug in a parachain?

```
DEBUG parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] received an unexpected `CollationSeconded`: unknown statement candidate_hash=0x8236ef339b1c10b9de08e99eb091a6d0e67b168f6f5158294c14837277ce82c1 origin=PeerId("12D3KooWRkZhiRhsqmrQ28rt73K7V3aCBpqKrLGSXmZ99PTcTZby") traceID=173084875066935610577916474665854936784
```

I was able to find the location of the `debug` log here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/e628e486717a82527601f248e102fcaff9f27ef8/node/network/collator-protocol/src/collator_side/mod.rs#L760

<s>I suspect that this is caused by how zombienet overrides the chain spec. Will try to confirm that.</s>